# mysql performance tuning innodb_buffer_pool_size and warming the cache (select * vs select count(*))

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, cache

I have a couple of questions about tuning a MySQL (5.5) database. It seems the clients database server has never had any performance tuning done. Upon reading around, it seems the one thing is to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to "80% of the available RAM". Now, the physical size of the database is about 5Gig, and the available RAM on the server is 32Gigs. It seems to make no sense to me to make the `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 25G`.

At the moment I have set

`innodb_buffer_pool_size: "8G"
innodb_buffer_pool_instances: "8"
innodb_log_files_in_group: "2"
innodb_log_file_size: "1G"`

Which, reading around (and running mysql-tuner script) seems about sane.

My question is: Is it a *bad idea* to have a `buffer_pool_size` greater than the size of the database itself. Is it bad to effectively have all the data in the `buffer_pool` ?

## Warming the cache

The other part is warming the cache. Reading other posts on the net, the suggestion is to run a bunch of `select count (*) from <table>` to warm it. If I do that, I get the amount of RAM at point (1) in the picture below.

If instead I run `select * from <table>` I get a heap more RAM used. Which, I *assume* means that I have more data loaded into the cache. Which seems good to me.

[image: ram profile for counts]

Is it better to run `select *` or `select count(*)` for warming the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warmup**

If you have a secondary index on the table, `SELECT COUNT(*)...` will use that.  So the first "warming" fetched that index.  The second "warming" fetched the data; note that the hump is higher, since the data is bigger?

That is, `COUNT(*)` works *only* for an *InnoDB* table with *no* secondary keys.

This might work:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY);`

You are overdue for an upgrade.  With 5.6.3, there is `innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown` and `innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup`, which is better than your warmup script; it efficiently restores the buffer pool to whatever was in it.

**Buffer pool size**

5GB of data; 32GB of RAM --> 8GB sounds like a good buffer_pool_size:

- Less than 5GB *probably* leads to extra I/O (depending on "working set size").
- 8GB leaves enough room on top of the 5GB for the "Change Buffer" and other overhead.
- 8-25GB -- the rest would be idle.
- over 25GB -- threaten to do swapping, which would be really bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is NOT a bad idea to have innodb_buffer_pool_size greater than the size of the database.

Some reasons why,
A: innodb_change_buffer_max_size default of 25% is set aside for data management in RAM.  If you ask for 100M, only 75M is effectively available.
You can manage this percentage in your my.cnf/ini - be conservative and analyze 
GLOBAL STATUS Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total for percentage of miscellaneous pages in use at this time.

B. Are you going to add/modify data to your database each day?  Then you will want to have a reasonable cushion for activity.

Reasonable limits? 
(Database size * 1.25) * 1.2 )   if you expect 10% growth in the near term.
Just so you have some cushion.  Review capacity in 90 days.

Database size * 3 = likely overkill.  Remember you probably have only so much RAM and simple math must be tempered with reality of available RAM.  Or acquire more RAM.